# US visa approved, but passport is stuck at the US consulate?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, h1b-visas

I appeared for an H1B visa interview at the Mumbai Consulate and was granted a visa. However it’s been over a week and my passport is not available for pickup. I have tried to contact the consulate via email and phone but I get nothing more than preformed responses. The online tracking shows no progress on my passport since last Friday. What are my options in terms of getting real information from the US Consulate, regarding my passport?

Comment: Why can you not wait for them to contact you? Is there some urgent need that you must have the passport back *right now*? (Eg another trip, visa application, etc) All bureaucracies take time to do lots of nothing.

Comment: My interview was on 1/2/2019 and it’s beyond the normal processing time of 3 to 5 days. I work in the US and I had to reschedule my travel two times as I don’t have my passport with me.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The people working at the consulate are currently not getting paid, and many of them may be under instructions not to report to work.

Comment: Er, I don't know why you pinged me about that. I am aware of the shut down.

Comment: Per: https://twitter.com/usandmumbai/status/1076485401567784961?s=12 the Consulate is open during shutdown

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I pinged you because "All bureaucracies take time to do lots of nothing" is advice for the general case, while the US bureaucracy is, at the moment, in an exceptional situation.

Comment: @SaurabhAjmera that the consulate is open does not imply that visa processing is proceeding normally.  Even if visa appointments are being honored, clerical support may be reduced and processing times therefore increased.